# Sublime Text 2 does not work from the command line after installing OS X Mavericks

Tags: sublimetext2, osx-mavericks

After installing OS X Mavericks, I noticed I can no longer launch Sublime Text 2 from the command line by typing 'subl'.  I looked online at the Sublime Text docs and in Stack Overflow and created a symbolic link here:

```
Christophers-MacBook-Pro-2:bin christopherspears$ pwd
/usr/local/bin
Christophers-MacBook-Pro-2:bin christopherspears$ ll
lrwxr-xr-x  1 christopherspears  staff       62 Mar  6 15:24 subl@ -> /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

I then looked in my .bash_profile file:

```
Christophers-MacBook-Pro-2:~ christopherspears$ cat .bash_profile 
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

# Set your default text editor
export EDITOR=subl
```

Seems like /usr/local/bin is in $PATH:

```
Christophers-MacBook-Pro-2:~ christopherspears$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/share/python:/Users/christopherspears/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Sublime Text 2 from Mac OS X and installed Sublime Text 3 (just wanted to check out the beta).  Then I created a link in my home directory (/Users/christopherspears/bin):

```
Christophers-MacBook-Pro-2:bin christopherspears$ la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   3 christopherspears  staff   102 Mar  7 18:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 57 christopherspears  staff  1938 Mar  7 19:00 ../
lrwxr-xr-x   1 christopherspears  staff    62 Mar  7 18:41 subl@ -> /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

Had to create the 'bin' directory myself.  Added the following to my .bash_profile:

```
# Set your default text editor
export EDITOR='subl -w'
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```